# How to host Tesseract OCR for a Chrome Extension?

Tags: google-chrome-extensions, hosting, tesseract-ocr

Currently, I'm working on designing a Google Chrome Extension that takes an image. This image supposes to be passed to Tesseract OCR using the command (cmd) and get the output as a text. A text area in the extension will show the result. I don't know where could I start with hosting Tesseract OCR and use it to compute the output of the image?
Note: I did also design an Android application for the same purpose.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install Tesseract according to the instructions in the wiki: https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/wiki